# ASP.NET Core: Redirect to Proper Site URL as Stated in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a site hosted at a URL like this:
domain.com/myApp/

When a user goes to domain.com/myapp/ (lowercase *a*), I want it to redirect to domain.com/myApp/ (uppercase *A*), just as stated in IIS.

I need to deploy this code to multiple domains on multiple servers, and I need each one to redirect to its own correct URL with the correct case. So the correct URL must be read from some data source and not hard coded.

I am very close to being able to perform the redirection, but I don't know how to retrieve the site's URL from IIS. I have tried `builder.Configuration[WebHostDefaults.ServerUrlsKey]` and `builder.WebHost.GetSetting(WebHostDefaults.ServerUrlsKey)`, and while they work locally, they return `null` on the server.

So how can an ASP.NET Core site know the exact hosted site URL (not just the URL in the request)? Alternatively, how can ASP.NET Core redirect to the correctly cased URL automatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `domain.com/myapp/` redirect to `domain.com/myApp/`. Why not create a simple rewrite rule using the rewrite module in IIS? Just like below:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^myapp(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="myApp(.*)" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: This solution would require me to make individual changes to each site. Instead, I'm looking for a solution that works for all sites without manual changes. Thank you though.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a custom middleware in your ASP.NET Core application to handle redirects. This middleware should be placed as early in the middleware pipeline as possible to intercept requests before they are processed by the application. In your custom middleware, you can check if the request URL matches the incorrect casing  ("/myapp/"). If so, it performs a permanent (301) redirect to the correct casing ("/myApp/").

Comment: Thank you, but redirection is the easy part. I'm looking for a way to read IIS data to know the correct case so I can perform the redirection.